# How can I optimize a large DisplayObject for tweening?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm writing a small AIR application that loads a presentation from a server and transitions through the slides using TweenMax. Each `Slide` object within the loaded presentation contains basic information about the slide, telling the `Renderer` class how to draw it (things like where a TextField should be, what its text should be, any filters that should be applied to the TextField, etc).

The `Renderer` then creates a Bitmap using the provided specifications, and that Bitmap is then given an alpha of 0 and tweened in using `TweenMax.to`.

I have a relatively powerful machine, one that should be able to handle such a task no problem. However, when I tween the Bitmap in, the framerate drops from a capped 60fps to around *11fps*. The output resolution (the size of the generated `Bitmap`) is only 1436x1076.

My question is: ***is there anything else I can do to improve the performance of my application?***

All tips are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: That's not a big image, any tween engine should be able to render this without problem or fps drop. Your code might be the issue.

Comment: Can you tell what else is on your stage, i.e. what are the other items which could be taking up memory? After the renderer creates the Bitmap, do you dispose off everything else which is not needed, like the TextField etc?

Comment: I join the chorus: There must be a performance bug in your code. Framerates usally go up when a bitmap is tweened. Vector-Data takes up a lot of processing power. TweenMax can handle Bitmaps and Vector with ease. Let us see some code.